# How do I add an openLDAP contrib module with cn=config layout to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I'm trying to get the pw-radius module loaded into my Ubuntu 12.04 slapd server but not sure how to go about it. Going off the [README](http://www.openldap.org/devel//cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/README?rev=1.11&hideattic=1&sortbydate=0) file in the passwd module directory, I've built the pw-radius module but not sure how to write the LDIF file to add it to my Ubuntu slapd server (cn=config layout). The README only shows how to configure for slapd.conf:

```
To use the RADIUS plugin, add:

moduleload pw-radius.so

to your slapd configuration file; optionally, the path to a configuration
file can be appended in the form

moduleload pw-radius.so config="/etc/radius.conf"
```

If I use the Ubuntu documentation LDIF for loading the syncprov module I could try something like this, but where would the bit about "/etc/radius.conf" go? Right after the module name as it is show in ldap.conf?

```
#Load the syncprov and accesslog modules. 
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: pw-radius.so config="/etc/radius.conf"
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the pw-freeradiusclient plugin and this is the ldif to add it. It uses the installed config files in /etc/radiusclient/ (obtained from install of libfreeradius2 on ubuntu 14.04)

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: pw-freeradiusclient


ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f pw.ldif
```